# How to launch a different viewController on the second launch

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here the code I have under the viewController.m

This code will run when a user selects a viewController

```
-(void)switchViews {
    UIStoryboard *mainStory = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [mainStory instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:schoolName];
    [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];

    NSUserDefaults *defaultViewController = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaultViewController setObject:nil forKey:@"save"];
    [defaultViewController synchronize];

}
```

This code will run on the second time the app is launched

```
-(void)loadNewView {
    UIStoryboard *mainStory = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    NSUserDefaults *newUserDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *newVC = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"save", schoolName];
    UIViewController *newViewController = [mainStory instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:newVC];
    [self presentModalViewController:newViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Keeping in mind that `schoolName`is a string

How can I run `[self loadNewView]` under the viewDidLoad but running it on the second time the app is launched?

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like

```
id value = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"save"];
if (value) {
   UIViewController *vc = [mainStory instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:value];
   [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
} else {
   // first time logic
}
```

in your `AppDelegate` or wherever you have your navigation logic. You should not have that logic in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *launchCount = @"LaunchCount";
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger count;
    if([userDefaults objectForKey:launchCount]) {
        count = [userDefaults integerForKey:launchCount];
    }
    else {
        count = 0;
    }
    count++; //increment the launch count
    [userDefaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:count] forKey:launchCount];
    [userDefaults synchronize];

    if([userDefaults integerForKey:launchCount] >= 2) {
       // Do your thang
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on ViewDidLoad function do something like this

```
 if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedFirst"])
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLauncheFirst"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

[self switchViews];
    }
else
{
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:No forKey:@"HasLauncheFirst"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

[self loadNewView];
}
```